# Situations where a move to a function is actually wanted in Rust

Tags: function, pointers, reference, rust, move

I'd like to determine in which general (or specific) situations one would not want to use a reference to pass an object into a function in Rust.

I'm mostly interested in *functionality* (e.g. a function is made so that it cleans up a resource moved into it), but *performance* reasons would also be interesting (e.g. if it was the case that it's faster to copy a small structure than access it through a pointer).

This regards non-`Copy` types, of course.

Note: it's clear why move semantics are used in *assignments*, in order to prevent aliasing e.g., but in functions that would not be a problem.

Comment: *if it was the case that it's faster to copy a small structure than access it through a pointer* - it is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there should be an obviously "best" answer, and questions asking for "lists of reasons" tend to be open-ended and have all equally valid answers.

Comment: (otherwise, for a cool application, search for "session types in Rust" on Google, or in general think about encoding state machines with such a system: it's guaranteed you won't move from an obsolete state!)

Comment: I just wanted to note that such a question would probably be welcome on either r/rust or on users.rust-lang.org.

Comment: @Shepmaster That's what I thought. However, it would be an easy optimization to make, wouldn't it? The semantics wouldn't change if it was all immutable.

Answer (score 2):

There are some situations like that, all of them are related to lifetime of structure, i.e. I'm writing Octavo (crypto library) where we have some hash functions (i.e. SHA1):

```
let mut digest = SHA1::new();
digest.update("Ala ma kota!");

let result = digest.result(); // here we invalidate digest as it finished its work
```

Other usage for case like above is builder pattern:

```
PizzaBuilder::new()
    .add_sauce()
    .add_cheese()
    .add_topping(Topping::Tomato)
    .add_topping(Topping::Bacon)
    .add_topping(Topping::Jalapenio)
    .bake() // here we destroy PizzaBuilder as this setup isn't usable  anymore
            // you should create new PizzaBuilder for another pizza
            // (you cannot reuse dough once you bake pizza)
```

Comment: `// here we invalidate digest as it finished its work` -- can you elaborate? Also, your second example as well. How is `PizzaBuilder` destroyed? And what does bake do?

Comment: In most implementations the hash engine has inner state (i.e. `bool`) that signals if it has calculated the hash (as it adds data to the message and do some more fancy things). In Rust instead of that additional inner state I just  destroy engine. About second question `PizzaBuilder::bake(self) -> Pizza` is method that bake (create) your pizza.

Comment: OK so the mechanism which destroys/invalidates these objects is a method that takes `self` through a move?

Comment: Yes. See the @Veedrac answer where he states that when you change one object into another then you want to invalidate old one to keep it safe (changing slice into Vec invalidates values inside slice, changing `Result` into `Option` does the same, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Consider a conversion function `fn(T) -> U`. If `T` was taken by reference, all operations on `U` would be required to uphold the invariants in `T`. This means that one would not be allowed to destroy `T` in any way. Further, the caller would be responsible for keeping the input in place in order for `U` to remain valid. A good example is `Vec::into_boxed_slice`.

Another example is a function that moves its input. Evidently this cannot accept a `&mut` without worrisome semantics. An example would be `Vec::insert`.

Another option is when `&mut Trait: Trait`. In this case taking `T: Trait` allows the caller to decide whether to borrow with dynamic dispatch or pass arguments, which has ramifications for ease of use (in both directions), speed and code bloat.

Another example might just be the preference of convenient syntax for the common case, where cloning is cheap. An example could be `Index<Range<usize>>` for `Vec`.

There are also compelling safety reasons if you want to restrict the number of times a function can be called on a given object. The simplest example is `drop`, which you rightly can only call once. A very fancy example are "session types" for channel communication.

Comment: *A good example is `Vec::into_boxed_slice`.* -- could you elaborate?

Comment: @jco Consider if `Vec::into_boxed_slice` merely borrowed the `Vec`. You then couldn't move the boxed slice into an object that might outlive the `Vec`, or even just move the `Vec` somewhere to make it live longer. Further, when the `Box<[T]>` is destroyed, it deallocates its memory... leaving the `Vec` invalid! You could get around this by making `into_boxed_slice` leave the `Vec` empty, but that seems like a strange contrivance to get sane behaviour. Plus, `mem::replace(&mut vec, vec![]).into_boxed_slice()` does the same thing if you really want it.

Answer (score 0):

One of applications of move semantics is type-safe state machines. Suppose that you have an object which can be in two states, uninitialized and initialized, and going from uninitialized to initialized has side effects and can possibly fail. This is naturally modeled with two types with a transition method which accepts an object of the first type by value and returns an object of the second type:

```
pub struct UninitFoo {
    ...
}

impl UninitFoo {
    pub fn new() -> UninitFoo { ... }
    pub fn configure_something(&mut self) { ... }
    pub fn configure_something else(&mut self) { ... }
    pub fn initialize(self) -> Result<InitFoo, SomeError> { ... }
}

pub struct InitFoo {
    ...
}

impl InitFoo {
    pub fn do_some_work(&mut self) { ... }
}
```

The example above is really contrived but I guess you get the idea. This way your set of types essentially forms a state machine, where methods like `initialize()` are transitions between states.